# Is a Turing Machine That Runs in Polynomial Time, But Has an Exponential Description, Polynomial or Exponential?

Tags: computational-complexity, turing-machines

Title says it all, but in other words, does the length of the description of a Turing Machine also affect its complexity? Or is its complexity only affected by its running time?

An example of such a machine could be one that has a "branch" for each symbol of input in a tree: the first branch would be for the first symbol of input, then there would be a branch in both sides of the first branch for the second symbol of input, etc. This machine would run in linear time (one branch for every symbol), but it would have an exponential description ($2^n - 1$ states).

Comment: The length of the description of a Turing Machine (the length of your program) is always $\mathcal{O}(1)$, a finite constant independent of the input. (The length of your Python script is always a constant independent of the input.) I don't think it makes sense to talk about "exponential description", unless you're talking about something else.

Comment: I am talking about the description. Based on your answer though, my thinking was wrong.

My thought was that a TM might be exponential if the description was because if the description is "exponential", the TM might become exponential in the same way that exponential input makes a TM take exponential time.

However, you answered the question. Would you like to make an official answer that I can accept and upvote?

Comment: I think what you thought was not possible. We can see this in another way. From the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine#Formal_definition) of TM, the number of states $|Q|$ of a TM is always a finite constant, independent of the input. So it does not make sense to talk about exponential number of states / description. It only makes sense to talk about exponential time complexity / exponential space complexity.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I learned something today: a TM's description does not affect its complexity. I'm sorry I worded the question poorly.